# Finding a chain homotopy

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

> Consider the chain complex $$C_{\ast}=(\dots\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\overset{\cdot 2}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\overset{\cdot 2}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\dots).$$

At first I have calculated the homology groups as $H_n(C)=Z_n/B_n=\{0,2\}/\{0,2\}=0$ for all $n$.

> Now I want to see if there is a chain homotopy from the identity of $C_{\ast}$ to the zero map.

So all I have to do is finding for every $n$ maps $s_n:\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ with $$d_{n+1}\circ s_n+s_{n-1}\circ d_n=\text{id}_{\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}}.$$

But I am not able to finde those. Any hints?

EDIT:
In our situation, for $[m]\in\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ the equation yields $$[m]=2s_n([m])+s_{n-1}([2m])=2s_n([m])+2s_{n-1}([m])=2(s_n([m])+s_{n-1}([m])).$$
But now the r.h.s.is element in $\{[0],[2]\}$. So there are no such $s_n$.

Comment: notice (by the definition of your $d$) that $(d_{n+1}\circ s_n+s_{n-1}\circ d_n)(x)$ is automatically a multiple of $2$, so $s$ doesn't exist

Comment: May you explain this in more details please? :)

Comment: I have edited. Is it right now?

Comment: yes ${{{{{}}}}}$

Comment: And the homology groups are right as well?